# Git - replicanting correction between branches

Tags: git

My application has only one file: File A.

I was in the v1.0 branch of GIT and I checkout to branch v1.1 where I started adding new functions to my application (File A).

Later, I detected and corrected an error in an function in File A on branch v1.0.

What is the correct way using GIT to replicate this correction to File A on branch v1.1?

Comment: There might not be a good Git-based way. Git is about commits, not files; it doesn't sound like this has anything to do with commits. If changing that file was the _only_ thing you did in a commit, you could cherry-pick that commit. Otherwise, though, just fix the file the same way in the other branch; i.e., it would be perfectly ok to copy the file from the fixed branch into the other branch and just commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On branch 1.0 check the relevant commit's hash, then

```
git checkout branch/1.1
git cherry-pick {commit hash here}
```

Other option, if 1.1 should be updated with everything that's new in 1.0 (for example, if the single commit *is* everything that's new in 1.0), is rebase.

```
git checkout branch/1.1
git rebase branch/1.0
```

Comment: `cherry-pick` ok, `rebase` ok, but why not `merge`?

Comment: That's an option, too, but makes for messier commit history. Although I admit it's kind of arbitrary. I thought of `1.0` as the develop branch and `1.1` as a feature branch, and in such situations I prefer rebase over merge to avoid merge commit noise in the commit history.